# View version control progress graphically

Tags: svn, git, macos

Is there a software for mac that lets me view the progress of the branches in either git or svn like in this image (from [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/))

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best visual client for Git on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455698/best-visual-client-for-git-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Git Web Access](http://gitweb.codeplex.com/) implements a new kind of visualization which is inspired by schacon's drawings in ProGit.

*Note:* Although not a desktop application, it should work on a Mac (with some help from Safari) **;-)**

See below an example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not to the level of the above given picture, but I find `git log --graph` and `gitk` to be good enough visual indicators.